# Stumped trying to target elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm really struggling to target an element in jQuery and would appreciate some help to see if it's possible.

My HTML is structure like this…

```
<p>Slimming World Nutritionist Jenny Allan says: “Ban the ‘D’ word. It has so many negative associations for most people, making them think of being deprived and not being able to share meals with family and friends and enjoy social events.”</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="pinit aligncenter" data-indexer="1">
    <div class="img-caption">Lose weight and feel great a your wedding!</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <noscript><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-33687" title="Lose weight and feel great a your wedding!" alt="danielle-david-real-wedding-05" src="http://www.giraffetest.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/danielle-david-real-wedding-05.jpg" width="650" height="433" /></noscript>
</p>
<h2>Myth 4 – Healthy eating is expensive</h2>
<div data-indexer="2"></div>
<p>“Your weekly shop will go further, your overall food bills won’t go up – and neither will your weight.”</p>`
```

I would like to select all images inside a div with a class of pinit, if the parent (in this case a

tag) is immediately followed by a h2 tag - which it is in this example.

I've tried the following but it's not working :-(

```
jQuery(".pinit").parent().next("h2").css("marginBottom", "0");
```

Can anyone help please?

Thanks,

James

Comment: What you're currently doing is targeting the `h2` and applying a style to it. I'd suggest running an `if` and then applying your styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
jQuery(".pinit").each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).parent().next("h2").length) {
        jQuery(this).children("img").css("marginBottom", "0");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - What about if I wanted to target an img inside the pinit class div? Would I need to use the .children() selector?

Comment: Testing .length only already does the trick. No need for "> 0"

Comment: Do I need to change the .parent() as well as I think targeting '.pinit img' will change the node level?

Comment: @JamesPayne -- Ignore my previous comment about the selector, you were right with the `.children()`, a quick fix. See the new answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".pinit").filter(function(){
    return jQuery(this).parent().next("h2").length > 0;
}).css("marginBottom", "0");
```

Basically `filter` is used to filter the set of `.pinit` elements down to only those which have a parent followed by an `h2`.  Then the remaining `.pinit` elements have `css` applied.